# "Direct3D Feature Level 11 unsupported." under the environment of Win7 + VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, directx, directx-11

I have just started learning D3D recently. I have setup my environment in accordance with the online tutorial I am following, but there was a problem when I ran the Chapter 6 BOX source of Luna's book about DX11.

I get the following [dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2REk.jpg) when running ("Direct3D Feature Level 11 unsupported.")

The code segment of the problem：

```
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel;
HRESULT hr = D3D11CreateDevice(
        0,                 // default adapter
        md3dDriverType,
        0,                 // no software device
        createDeviceFlags, 
        0, 0,              // default feature level array
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &md3dDevice,
        &featureLevel,
        &md3dImmediateContext);

if( FAILED(hr) )
{
    MessageBox(0, L"D3D11CreateDevice Failed.", 0, 0);
    return false;
}

if( featureLevel != D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0 )
{
    MessageBox(0, L"Direct3D Feature Level 11 unsupported.", 0, 0);
    return false;
}
```

I found a similar problem on the stackoverflow ([Two problems while initializing Directx 11.0 - 1.FeatureLevel, 2. 4xMSAA quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26035897/two-problems-while-initializing-directx-11-0-1-featurelevel-2-4xmsaa-quality)),
but the answers do not solve my problem. I have updated my graphics driver.

I've used the DxDiag tool and the results are as follows:

[dxdiag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svfZY.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 includes the DirectX 11 API, but that doesn't mean you have a DirectX 11 capable piece of video hardware. DirectX 11 (the API) supports a range of video hardware that are arranged into [Direct3D hardware feature levels](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels/). Just because your current driver/card doesn't support 11.0, it may support 10.1 or 10.0 which has many (but not all) the same [features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876.aspx).

> On Windows 8 or later, there are additional feature levels beyond 11.0 you can request. By default, if you pass `nullptr` to the default feature level array, it will only return 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 10.0, 10.1, or 11.0.
>
> Note that on Windows 7 Service Pack 1, the DirectX 11.1 Runtime can be installed but it does not support the newer driver model. Therefore, you can't use Direct3D hardware Feature Level 11.1--these cards all support 11.0 so you can fallback to that. See [DirectX 11.1 and Windows 7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/11/13/directx-11-1-and-windows-7/). DirectX 11.2 and beyond are not available for Windows 7.

Frank Luna's source assumes you have a 11.0 capable video card for simplicity, but you can still do many things with an older card. See [Anatomy of Direct3D 11 Create Device](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/02/05/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/) for details on how to create a device with a range of feature levels.

Alternatively, you can get a newer video card.

> As you are new to DirectX development, be sure to read [Book Recommendations](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/04/07/book-recommendations/) for notes on some aspects of Luna's book that were out-of-date shortly after the print date of the book. You may also want to look at the [DirectX Tool Kit tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Finally, consider moving to a more recent version of Visual Studio. At this point, most of the modern [DirectX supporting libraries](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) won't build with VS 2010 as it only had a few C++11 draft language features implemented. You should take a look at using [VS Community edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) which is free as long as you meet the license requirements.

Comment: I think that I should change a computer.But in any case thank you for answering my question

Answer (score 0):

Just because your graphics drivers are up to date, does not mean that they support the `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0`. It's unclear which video card you actually have from your DxDiag, but the default specs for the [HP 3005 MT](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01926406) show the best available card as the Nvidia 315, and it only supports DirectX 10.1.

At stated in the documentation for `D3D11CreateDeivce`:

> If pFeatureLevels is set to NULL, this function uses the following
>   array of feature levels:
>
> {
>       D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
>       D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
>       D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
>       D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
>       D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
>       D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1, };

Meaning that the function will succeed if any of these feature levels is supported by your device (it will attempt them in order). Likely, it's giving you a device where `featureLevel` is `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1` (or lower, depending on the actual card). Time to buy a new video card.

Comment: I think that I should change a computer.But in any case thank you for answering my question